# Should two attempts for same reduce tasks continue to run in parallel?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The actions in my hadoop reduce task have external effects, and they are not idempotent. And I have observed in task tracker that one reducer was attempted and then another reducer for same set of keys was started without killing the original one. Have I configured something wrong?

Here is the table for this reduce task:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to speculative execution in hadoop. It is the option for Hadoop to specify backup tasks if it detects that there are some slow tasks on a few of the cluster nodes.  The backup tasks will be preferentially scheduled on the faster nodes.  Whichever of the duplicate tasks finishes first becomes the one that is used in further operations.

you can turn this off by setting the following parameter as false

```
mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution
```

Comment: I found it here after asking: 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml
`mapreduce.map.speculative` and
`mapreduce.reduce.speculative`